# Linking a .css to .html not working at all

Tags: html, css

```
<html  lang="en">
<head>
  <title>My Resume</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <style type="text/css">

   body {
     background:        #007F5A /* spanish viridian */
    }

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</div>

</style>

 </head>
 <body>
```

I have no idea why my .css file will not go in and link up with my .html any suggestions? BTW using NotePad++ as an editor.

Comment: Why do you have `</div>` inside the header?

Comment: I was completely unaware of that. even after removing it I still cannot seem to get this style.css to feed into my html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your tags all mixed up.  Try this instead:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My Resume</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: #007F5A /* spanish viridian */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is not right.

why theres a `</div>` in the `<head>`? you must put the end tag `</style>` before `<link href="style.css"` line ;)

I fixed the code for you!

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My Resume</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background: #007F5A /* spanish viridian */
    }
    </style>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

good luck !

Answer (score 0):

`<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` is HTML that you are putting inside a `style` tag, where CSS is supposed to go, so it doesn't work.

Move that `link` tag to outside the `style` tag, like this:

```
<style type="text/css">

    body {
        background: #007F5A /* spanish viridian */
    }

</style>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Also, `</div>` isn't closing anything so it is pointless; remove it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few couple of blatant issues here:

1. You're including the link tag within a style tag
2. There's a <div> tag in the <head> and a <style> tag

Correctly structured it should be like this:

```html
<html  lang="en">
<head>
  <title>My Resume</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <style type="text/css">
   body {
     background:        #007F5A /* spanish viridian */
    }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there are few errors in your `markup`, so let's start here:

remove the `div` that's inside the `style` tag because that's not a `CSS` rule.

remove the line below that's inside the `style` tag.

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css>
```

follow best practises by inserting it into the `head` tag:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

so now your `markup` becomes like this:

```
<html  lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My Resume</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
       body {
         background:#007F5A; /* spanish viridian */
       }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

if all else fails, get rid of the links and just place ur styling code in between these tags on your .html page

```
<style>
<!-your gorgeous styling in here ->
</style>
```